# How to set alarm at a specific date and time?

Tags: notifications, alarm

My phone is a Huawei Ascend Y511 with Android 4.2.2.

I like the Alarms feature in the built-in Clock app, but it only lets me choose a time (and days of the week, if using a recurring alarm), not a date. Any way to set an alarm (reminder) for a specific date and time?

I don't wanna use Google Now's reminders, as I don't like GNow from a privacy standpoint. I tried Google Keep which works but only produces a one-off, short sound, rather than a looped melody, and doesn't show any notification on the screen except a tiny icon in the top black bar.

I'd like something that works close to the Clock app: show a full-screen notification that lets me drag an icon in one of two directions to either snooze or discard the reminder. And don't stop playing the sound until I react.

Comment: What is a full-screen notification? Anyhow, you can have [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) to create a persistent notification or a full-screen dialog or scene or name it, on a particular day/date or time . You can configure Tasker to continue to play the sound unless you take an action. The action can be in the form of button or even touch gestures (if you use Plugins).

Comment: @Firelord: A full screen notification is what the Clock app gives me - a screen with a slidable button on it, which doesn't go away until I choose an option on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use [Early Bird Alarm Clock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.funanduseful.earlybirdalarm)**.

It has all the features that you wanted.

> ✔ Select alarm date for shift worker
>   Complete schedule such as day-night-off-holiday will be okay!

Comment: Third-party apps face the risk of being killed by the Android OS. Your app also contains advertising.

Comment: After some testing, the app works as promised and there are instructions for configuring Android's battery optimization settings. Internet access isn't mandatory.